# Move whole line up/down shortcut in nano (analogue to intelliJ or Visual Studio)

Tags: linux, bash, editor, nano

How to move a line of text up/down in [Nano linux command line editor](http://www.nano-editor.org/)?

Is there any analogue way to do that as in [IntelliJ Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/adding-deleting-and-moving-lines.html#d1591098e152):

1. Place the caret at the line to be moved.
2. Do one of the following:

On the main menu, choose `Code | Move Line Up or Code | Move Line Down`.

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to cut a line, move to destination position and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to paste it.